# Excel Query to update a Worksheet doesnt keep formats

Tags: excel

im trying to update a worksheet, by using queries. Now i have a problem, cause the imported Data keeps getting turned into a table , although the resource Data is not a table.

Basically i want the columns A:E in worksheet(x), to get updated with columns A:E from worksheet(xyz) and keep the formatting from worksheet(xyz).

Answer (score 0):

Power Query always returns output in the form of table as it's easier to address the respective data positions via vectors. assume you have 2 queries, then it's much easier to merge/append since they are treated as relational data tables.

you can always convert the output table back to range but the connection to query will be lost.

Comment: So you mean the 1st query draws me a table and then i create a second query, that references to the 1st one and this then isnt in a table form ? Did i understand you correctly?